# Python Classes not acting distinct?

Tags: python, class

I am trying to write a program which contains a class called compound. A basic form of this class is here;

```
class Compound:
    def __init__(self, name="", entropy=0, enthalpy=0, constituents=[]):
        self.constituents = constituents
        self.name = name
        self.entropy = entropy
        self.enthalpy = enthalpy
        self.check_data()
        if (name != ""):
            self.find_constituents()
    def find_constituents(self):
        name = self.name
        if (len(name) == 0):
            return 0
        name = re.sub(r'\([a-z]+\)', '', name)
        p = re.findall(r'\d+', name[0])
        if (len(p) > 0):
            name = name[1:]
            lop = int(p[0])
        else:
            lop = 1
        chem = re.findall('[A-Z][a-z0-9]{0,3}', name)
        for p in chem:
            l = re.findall(r'\d+', p)
            if (len(l) == 1):
                num = int(l[0])
            else:
                num = 1
            q = re.sub(r'\d+', '', p)
            print q
            try:
                for l in range(0, num):
                    for ki in range(0, lop):
                        self.constituents.append(q)
            except:
                print("Element "+q+" not found.")
```

In essence, all it does is take the name as input, and if the name is not "" it then tries to break it down to components and put these into constituents - so, F2 will put [F, F] in constituents, NaOH will put [Na, O, H] and so on.

When running this with a single Compound, it works perfectly;

```
>>> a = Compound("F2")
Data not found
F
>>> print vars(a)
{'constituents': ['F', 'F'], 'entropy': 0, 'name': 'F2', 'enthalpy': 0}
```

When I run it again, but before printing I assign another variable, b, to a different compound;

```
>>> a = Compound("F2")
Data not found
F
>>> b = Compound("NaOH")
Data not found
Na
O
H
>>> print vars(a)
{'constituents': ['F', 'F', 'Na', 'O', 'H', 'F', 'F', 'Na', 'O', 'H'], 'entropy': 0, 'name': 'F2', 'enthalpy': 0}
```

It has for some reason changed the value of a.constituents in this reassignment. I have no idea why this is as it is. From what I can see, given that the other values (name for instance) have not changed it would imply it is within the find_constituents() part. Given, however, that find_constituents does not use any external variables I cannot see why this would be happening.

Could anyone lend any light to the problem? Thanks!

Comment: Hi, I had a look on the page and it seems to be the same issue - getting rid of the default values in the __init__() function fixed it. Thank you!

Comment: Yes, that is, unfortunately, a classic mistake. Never use mutable objects (lists, dicts) as default values for functions. They persist across calls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your default value for `constituents`, `[]`, is shared across all calls to the constructor.  I suggest simply copying the list when assigning `constituents` to `self`:

```
self.constituents = constituents[:]
```

That way you're safe no matter what's passed in.

Comment: That's potentially inefficient; the `None` default value is generally a better idea.

Comment: @johnrsharpe Well, it's less error prone, and in this case I don't think it's a problem.  Of course, it could do both:  Change `None` into a new `[]` and copy if it's already a list.